# Java MVC createsqlException when inserting confirmed cart into database (cannot be inserted)

Tags: java, model-view-controller, insert, connection, sqlexception

I need someone to help me check why the data is not recorded into database? When I try to "Check Out" the cart, the record of the cart is supposed to execute sql statement to transfer the data to the database. Here's the code and error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Data source rejected establishment of connection,  message from server: "Too many connections"
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1015)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:989)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:975)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1112)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2486)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2519)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2304)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:834)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor12.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:416)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:346)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at servlet.TicketDataBean.getConnection(TicketDataBean.java:16)
```

And the Code:

**Cart.jsp**

```
 <body>
    <form action="ConfirmPurchaseServlet" method="POST" style="text-align: right; margin-top: -40px;margin-right: 10px;">
                <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Check out" class="btn btn-success">
</form>
</body>
```

**ConfirmPurchaseServlet.java**

```
package place;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class ConfirmPurchaseServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/ConfirmPurchaseServlet")
public class ConfirmPurchaseServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException{
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();

        Cart cart = (Cart) session.getAttribute("Cart");
        try{
            cart.finishtransaction();

        }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
        response.sendRedirect(response.encodeRedirectURL("/ItineryAirport/CheckConfirmation.jsp")); //to another page
    }
    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public BillServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

**Cart.java**

```
public void finishtransaction()throws Exception{
        Enumeration e = items.elements();
        connection = TicketDataBean.getConnection();
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        totalPrice=0.00;

        while (e.hasMoreElements()){
            Flight item = (Flight) e.nextElement();
            String itemQuantity = "" + item.getQuantity();
            totalPrice = totalPrice + item.getPrice() * Integer.parseInt(itemQuantity);
            String tourCode = item.getTourcode();

            String updateString = "INSERT INTO cart " +
            " Values (" + CARTID + ", '" +
            item.getTitle() + "', '" +
                    item.getAirline() + "', '" +
                    item.getTravelto() + "', '" +
                    item.getTravelfrom() + "', " +
            item.getPrice() + ", " +
                    item.getQuantity() + ") ";
            statement.executeUpdate(updateString);
            System.out.println(statement);
            CARTID++;
            }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

close statements and database connections.  Having problems adding the code - but you need a try and finally block. In the finally block you can call

```
statement.close();
connection.close();
```

These statements should be in a finally block at the bottom of the finishTransactions() method or whatever that method name is.

because the error says you have no connections available.

Comment: Updated the answer - should be at bottom of finishTransaction() method.

Comment: seems like the error remains the same. Is there any other possibility why data could not be inserted?

Comment: What's the result?  Exception, nothing ?  The return value on statement.executeUpdate will tell you how many updates took place, check that?  Also, can you take the generated SQL statement and run it against MySQL at command line or in a GUI and see if that works?  And you may need to create a new statement each time inside your loop.